# Quickly sum a big list of lists?

Tags: r

I have a 10000 lists (results of a simulation), each containing 22500 lists (each list is a pixel in an image) which contains a vector of length 55.

```
# Simple Example
m <- replicate(2, list(runif(55))) 
m2 <- replicate(3, list(m)) 
str(m2,list.len = 3)

List of 3
 $ :List of 4
  ..$ : num [1:55] 0.107 0.715 0.826 0.582 0.604 ...
  ..$ : num [1:55] 0.949 0.389 0.645 0.331 0.698 ...
  ..$ : num [1:55] 0.138 0.207 0.32 0.442 0.721 ...
  .. [list output truncated]
 $ :List of 4
  ..$ : num [1:55] 0.107 0.715 0.826 0.582 0.604 ...
  ..$ : num [1:55] 0.949 0.389 0.645 0.331 0.698 ...
  ..$ : num [1:55] 0.138 0.207 0.32 0.442 0.721 ...
  .. [list output truncated]
 $ :List of 4
  ..$ : num [1:55] 0.107 0.715 0.826 0.582 0.604 ...
  ..$ : num [1:55] 0.949 0.389 0.645 0.331 0.698 ...
  ..$ : num [1:55] 0.138 0.207 0.32 0.442 0.721 ...
  .. [list output truncated]

# my function
m3 <- lapply(seq_along(m2[[1]]), FUN = function(j) Reduce('+', lapply(seq_along(m2), FUN = function(i) m2[[i]][[j]])))
#by hand
identical(m2[[1]][[1]] + m2[[2]][[1]] + m2[[3]][[1]], m3[[1]] )
```

I wrote a nested lapply with Reduce to sum the lists. On a small example, as in above, it's fast but on my real data, it's really slow.

```
#slow code
m <- replicate(22500, list(runif(55))) 
m2 <- replicate(10000, list(m)) 
str(m2,list.len = 3)
m3 <- lapply(seq_along(m2[[1]]), FUN = function(j) Reduce('+', lapply(seq_along(m2), FUN = function(i) m2[[i]][[j]])))
```

How can I speed this up, or should I change data structures?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This gives some improvement (>2x):

```
split(Reduce(`+`, lapply(m2, unlist)), rep(seq_along(m2[[1]]), lengths(m2[[1]])))
```

Since your data is essentially rectangular, had you stored it in this shape:

```
library(data.table)
d = rbindlist(lapply(m2, function(x) transpose(as.data.table(x))), id = T
             )[, id.in := 1:.N, by = .id]
#   .id        V1         V2           V55 id.in
#1:   1 0.4605065 0.09744975 ... 0.8620728     1
#2:   1 0.6666742 0.10435471 ... 0.3991940     2
#3:   2 0.4605065 0.09744975 ... 0.8620728     1
#4:   2 0.6666742 0.10435471 ... 0.3991940     2
#5:   3 0.4605065 0.09744975 ... 0.8620728     1
#6:   3 0.6666742 0.10435471 ... 0.3991940     2
```

You could do the aggregation even faster by doing:

```
d[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = id.in]
```

But if the list is your starting point, the conversion would take up the majority of the time.